# Don't know how to create this MySQL statement in sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following MySQL statement which does what I want:

```
SELECT scores.score, registrations.parade, AVG(scores.score) as result
FROM scores
JOIN registrations ON scores.registrationId=registrations.id
where registrations.parade=1
GROUP BY scores.registrationId
ORDER BY result DESC
```

basically, with sqlalchemy I think I would start with:

```
db.session.query(Scores, func.avg(Scores.score).label('result'))
```

This is because I do not need the information from registrations (it's linked to each other in the model). I only join the registrations in the MySQL statement because I need to filter on its parade.id

Below is what I have been trying so far but does not work:

```
scores = db.session.query(Scores,func.avg(Scores.score).label('result'))\
    .filter(Registrations.parade == 1)\
    .group_by(Scores.registrationId)\
    .order_by(desc('result'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `join`

```py
scores = db.session.query(Scores.score,func.avg(Scores.score).label('result'))\
    .join(Registrations)\
    .filter(Registrations.parade == 1)\
    .group_by(Scores.registrationId)\
    .order_by(desc('result'))
```

Another issue is, that you should have an aggretation function for `registrations.parade` or else include it in the `group_by` statement.

Comment: Many thanks. Thought the join was not necessary because of the filter conditions. I thought that would let sqlalchemy make the join itself.